# Incorrect wav header generated by sox

Tags: wav, sox, riff

I was using sox to convert a 2 channels, 48000Hz, 24bits wav file (new.wav) to a mono wav file (post.wav).
Here are the related commands and outputs:

```
[Farmer@Ubuntu recording]$ soxi new.wav 
Input File     : 'new.wav'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:01.52 = 72901 samples ~ 113.908 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 447k
Bit Rate       : 2.35M
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM

[Farmer@Ubuntu recording]$ sox new.wav -c 1 post.wav 
[Farmer@Ubuntu recording]$ soxi post.wav 

Input File     : 'post.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:01.52 = 72901 samples ~ 113.908 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 219k
Bit Rate       : 1.15M
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

It looks fine. But let us check the header of post.wav:

```
[Farmer@Ubuntu recording]$ xxd post.wav | head -10
00000000: 5249 4646 9856 0300 5741 5645 666d 7420  RIFF.V..WAVEfmt 
00000010: 2800 0000 feff 0100 80bb 0000 8032 0200  (............2..
00000020: 0300 1800 1600 1800 0400 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 1000 8000 00aa 0038 9b71 6661 6374  .........8.qfact
00000040: 0400 0000 c51c 0100 6461 7461 4f56 0300  ........dataOV..
```

This is the [standard wav file header structure](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).

The first line is no problem.

The second line "2800 0000" shows the size of sub chunk "fmt ", it should be 0x00000028 (as this is little endian) = 40 bytes. But there are 54 bytes (before sub chunk "fmt " and sub chunk "data").

The third line shows "ExtraParamSize" is 0x0018 = 22 bytes. But actually it is 36 bytes (from third line's "1600" to 5th line's "0100"). The previous 16 bytes are standard.

So what's the extra 36 bytes?

Comment: One confusion might come from `xxd` outputting big-endian by default. You need to supply the `-e` switch to have it show little-endian. (hint: you probably also want `-g2` with `-e`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,I found out the answer.
Look at the second line, we can found that audio format is "feff", actual value is 0xFFFE, so this is not a PCM standard wave format, but a extensible format.

Wav head detailed introduction can refer to [this link](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html). The article is well written and thanks to the author.

So as this is a Non-PCM format wav, "fmt " chunk space occupied 40 bytes is no problem， and followed by a "fact" chunk, and then is "data" chunk, So everything makes sense.